# How can I add a UserControl to a Panel on the main form?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am working on project winForm application. Am trying to add a UserControl to a Panel on the main Form.
Here is what I did, I created a public static method on the Main Form so I can call it from anywhere without instantiating the main form.

```
public static void showUC(UserControl uc)
    {
        pnlContainer.Controls.Clear();
        GC.Collect();
        uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pnlContainer.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

I am getting a compilation error "An object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property".

If I create the method as non-static the compilation error will be gone but I won't be able to call it without creating object of the main form.

What I want to achieve is to be able to open any UserControl inside the Panel 'pnlContainer' on my Main Form 'frmMain'.

When the main form loads I want to calling the method without instantiating the main form again. For example

```
public static void showUC(UserControl uc)
{
    pnlContainer.Controls.Clear();
    GC.Collect();
    uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

I want to be calling this method like this

```
frmMain.showUC(new ucClientList);
```

From another class.

Let me explain exactly what I want to achieve.
I have a Form Control named 'frmMain' which contain a panel control named 'pnlContainer' and I want to be loading UserControl into it, I have UserControl1 and UserControl2.
Now I run the program and the frmMain loads, I wants to add UserControl1 to the panel pnlContainer and I have a button inside the UserControl1 which is supposed to load UserControl2 into the same panel on the Main Form when I click on it. How do I implement this?

Comment: If you have a different way of implementing this please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do so you can write your code like this:

```
public static void showUC(Control uc, Control pnlContainer)
{
    pnlContainer.Controls.Clear();
    uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pnlContainer.Controls.Add(uc);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
showUC(new someControlType(), someControlContainer);
```

No need to call the `GC`; do leave it to the system to clean up matters!

And a `static` function needs to know **all** objects it is supposed to work with, so you need to pass in the container as well.

Finally `new` needs paranthesis with (optionally) parameters..

I made the signature of the new control `Control` so you can pass in any control; and for even more flexibility the container is also `Control`. Note that this still allows you to pass in the Form! Of course you may want to go back to more restricted types..

**Update**

If you want to switch between two `UserControls` that both sit in the same container you can use this function:

```
public static void showUC(Control uc)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in uc.Parent.Controls) ctl.Visible = ctl != uc;
}
```

It can access the other one via the `Parent` of the calling one. In the UC  write:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.showUC(this);
}
```

You could modify to actually create the `UserControls` instead of `Hiding/Showing` them; but you would lose their state each time..

If that is what you want, you may consider changing the name to something like `switchUcFrom` or `showOtherUC`; after all it doesn't 'show this' but rather 'hide this and show the other UC'

Comment: I have tried your answer and I noticed that I cannot access 'this.Controls.add(pnlContainer);' because the method is static. Please read the last paragraph of my question and know if you offer a different solution to it. @peter

Comment: Ah, your code got me confused. See my update. It also doesn't create/destroy the UCs but simply switches their visibility, so you should add both to the form first.